# Failed assertion: 'context != null': is not true

Tags: flutter

After having searched for a while on Google, I desperately ask for your help for a problem I can't solve by myself.
Shortly, I call an alert dialog and I receive the following error :
'package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart': Failed assertion: line 446 pos 12: 'context !=
null': is not true.

Here is the beginning of my code :
First file (class) from which I call the alert :
'''

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:testspourprojets/outils/alert_connexion.dart';
import 'package:testspourprojets/outils/test_fichier.dart';
import 'package:testspourprojets/pages/page_detail_commerce.dart';
import 'package:testspourprojets/outils/variables_globales.dart';
class PageCommerces extends StatefulWidget {
_PageCommerces createState() => new _PageCommerces();
}
class _PageCommerces extends State<PageCommerces> {
TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
List<Commercant>();
List<Commercant> dummySearchList = List<Commercant>();
List<Commercant> dummyListData = List<Commercant>();
@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
typePost = "commercant";
maLocalisation();
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return new Scaffold(
appBar: new AppBar(
title: new Text("Commerçants"),
leading: new Container(), //cache le bouton back dans la appBar
),
body: new Container(
color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
child: (maListeCommerces == null)? chargementEnCours(): listeRetour(),
),// fin container
);
}
Widget listeRetour(){
fonctionConversion();
triSurDistance();
BuildContext context;
message1 = "Test alerte";
message2 = "Message de test d'alerte";
print("context hashcode : $context.hashCode");
AlerteConnexion().methodeAlerte();//c'est ici que j'appelle mon alerte dans une autre classe
return new Container(
...
```

'''
Beside this I have my AlerteConnexion class in another file :
'''

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testspourprojets/pages/page_promotions.dart';
import 'package:testspourprojets/outils/variables_globales.dart';
class AlerteConnexion extends StatefulWidget {
_AlerteConnexion createState() => new _AlerteConnexion();
methodeAlerte() => createState().Alerte();
}
class _AlerteConnexion extends State<AlerteConnexion>{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
print("Dans AlerteConnexion");
return null;
}
void Alerte(){
//build(context);
print("Dans Alerte");
showDialog(
context: context,
barrierDismissible: true,
builder: (BuildContext contextAlert) {
return new AlertDialog(
title: new Text(message1, textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
content: new Text(message2),
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
actions: <Widget>[
new FlatButton(
onPressed: () {
print("Continuer");
Navigator.pop(contextAlert);
},
child: new Text(
"Continuer",
style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),))
],
);
},
);
}
}
```

'''

Note that if I place the alert in the first file/class, it doesn't work neither.
I am not a professional developper and I must confess that I have some difficulties to master (understand) the concepts of State and the place of the Widget in the tree (I even am not sure wether a function is a widget).
I thank you very much for your help !
Wish you a nice evening/day
Bernard

Comment: Please provide error logs that's relevant to the issue. The line `'package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart': Failed assertion: line 446 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true.` doesn't seem to suffice. A minimal repro of the issue will greatly help.